# Important tithis for Mahadeva?

Tags: shiva

What are the important *tithis* for Mahadeva?

Examples:

- *Mondays* are called auspicious for Mahadeva.
- *sukla paksha asthami* is auspicious for Devi Durga.

what are the tithis for Mahadeva?

Comment: In every month the 14th tithi of the Krishna paksha is called Masik Shivaratri ..  and this day in the Magha month is called Maha Shivaratri .. apart from this, in each month the two Trayodashi (13th) Tithis are days for pradosha vrata for Lord Shiva .. check on Drikpanchang.com for the dates of these two Vrata days.

Comment: Thanks @Rickross, Mashik Shivratri is mentioned is any Puran ?

Comment: Need to check that

Comment: One of my friends tells me that Masik Shivaratri is mentioned in Shiva and Varaha Puranas but at this moment does not have the exact references.

Comment: From here you can see about greatness of Shivaratri that comes every month (from Shiva Purana) -- https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226539.html

Answer (score 1):

The Trayodashi and Chaturdashi are important tithis for Lord Shiva.

1. **Trayodashi**

The Shiva Purana mentiones about Shiva's worship during Trayodashi. You can see it, [here](https://www.wisdomlib.org/index.php?type=search&division=text&input=Thirteenth&input_proximity=day&input_proximity_slop=&book_id=1392).

2. **Chaturdashi**

The Agni Purana says that one should be worship Lord Shiva at the Chaturdashi of Kartthika month.

> 1-10. I shall describe the vow (to be practised) on the fourteenth (lunar) day that would confer enjoyment and emancipation. One should fast on the fourteenth day in (the month of) kārttika (November-December) and worship (lord) Śiva.
>
> ***Course: Agni Purana, Chapter 192***

It implies that Chaturdashi is important to Lord Shiva.

---

Ok, that's it. I hope your doubt was cleared.

Comment: u mean both for krishna paksha ?

Comment: AFAIK, Trayodashi of Shukla Paksha is called Pradosha. But, i'm not sure what our scriptures deals with both are for Krishna or/and Shukla Paksha.

Comment: As shiva ratri on krishna paksha so i made a conclusion on that.

Comment: can you try to answer this question? https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/58246/source-of-durga-dwatrimsha-namavali-stotram

Comment: I'll answer if i find the source.

Answer (score 0):

All poornima days, and Pradhosham. Rest of auspicious days are based on family functions dedicated to God.

Comment: Why Poornima days are  auspicious for Mahadev? Is it mentioned is any scripture? Can you send me the reference?